# Clojure: leiningen (--force) and git interaction

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Suppose I have a (leiningen) project tree created by **git clone**. This may be a subset of a project created via lein new template, which is perfectly legitimate. There is a --force option to roll a lein project over a suitable source tree already in place -- or so I presume. I tried it, something like this:

```
$ lein new app alfa --force
```

It replaced all the source files with the template stubs. What am I getting wrong?

The seminal discussion: [issue #1467](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1467)

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting anything wrong here, this is the way the force option works. If your project already contains some subset of files and folders for a leiningen project, then they will be overwritten if they already exist in the project directory. This seems like conventional behavior considering the task that is being run is called "new." It's operating under the assumption that this is indeed a new project, but with a directory already created.

Comment: So far this kind of reasoning is a bit of a mystery to me. It implies that the existing directory is useless and may be either deleted manually beforehand or never created at all. lein idefiles task, for instance, exists for the obvious reason, and it is not destructive.

Comment: The way I would handle the scenario you're in would be to use lein new without the force option on a new directory, then copy the files from the local git directory into the newly created directory, overwriting the template files with the ones from git. Then set the upstream to point to your git repo in the new directory.

Comment: Well, if there's no other way... But what is the utility of the --force option?

Comment: Create a git repo, clone it to a directory on disk, run lein new... without force => error. Force option writes template files into existing directories. I think it was designed with that scenario in mind only. Would be nice to have a --no-overwrite option for that as well.